# How to name an object reference after a String

Tags: java, string, object, reference

For example, we have

```
String name = "Peter";
```

and we want the particular instance of a hypothetical `Employee` to be named after this string, as in

```
Employee ____ = new Employee(...);
```

So what do I have to put there?

Comment: Why do you want that? The program will work the same way no matter how you name local variables. The compiler even removes that information.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this can be done in Java . You can use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead, where the key will be employee name `"Peter"` and value will be the `Employee` object. But in that case you need to differentiate two `Employee` objects with the same name by overriding the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method using some other field of the `Employee` class.

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();
employeeMap.put("Peter",  new Employee("Peter")); // assuming you have this constructor
Employee e = employeeMap.get("Peter");
```

A better approach would be to use some unique `ID` as key for the `Map` like an employeeID.

If `Employee` has a field called "name" . You can set that either in constructor or using a setter method.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are *not relevant* in Java - they are lost after your code is compiled, and are merely a convenience for the programmer. Consequently, naming variables dynamically like that is not possible.

You could either make `name` a field of the `Employee` class or use a `Map<String, Employee>` as others have suggested. If you need a quick way to look-up employees by name, the latter option is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can only name the local variable holding the reference.

```
Employee peter = new Employee("peter");
```

If you want to be able to look up the employee my name you can do

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

employeeMap.put("peter",  new Employee("peter"));

Employee e = employeeMap.get("peter");
```